# color swatches & dropdown lists at the same time - shopify

Tags: e-commerce, shopify, variants

I am building an e-commerce site on shopify and I would like to add color swatches in the products but ONLY for one option (e.g. colors), not for all of them. I made all the changes according to this tutorial http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/add-color-swatches-to-your-products and it works fine but for all the option. Is there any way to display only one option as color swatches?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you've followed [this tutorial](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/showcasing-products/add-color-swatches-to-your-products), all you need to do to limit the swatches to one option is [put this in product.liquid](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/showcasing-products/add-color-swatches-to-your-products#include-your-swatch-liquid-file):

```
{% if product.available and product.variants.size > 1 %}
 {% include 'swatch' with 'Color' %}
{% endif %}
```

(replace `Color` with the name of the option you want to be swatches/buttons)